# Visual Studio 2010 break point on brace will skip to next code line when start debug

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I add a break point on left brace as below

```
catch
{   //I have a break point here
    somecode; //the break point skip to this line where I press F5 to start debug
}
```

this behavior in VS2010, is there any option to config this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no byte code associated with the line

```
{
```

so you cannot set a breakpoint there. However the behavior is the same. When you hit a breakpoint, execution stops before the line is executed.

Comment: In other vs2010 version, I can set break point on "{" and make code stop at "{" . Seems a config issue from my side.

Comment: @jojo are you building in debug mode?

Comment: yes, has checked the Solution property page. Platform is Any CPU. @clcto